# Return correctly the info in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use the [date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) of jQuery UI but I don't know how to extract the info because I'm calling the `datePickerRange()` function but it's always returning `object object`.

Below is the function that I have created, maybe is useless, but my idea was take from here the days selected.

```
function datePickerRange(){

    var from = $("#from").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#to").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });

    return from;
}
```

The `getDate()` function:

```
function getDate(element) {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy";
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }

    return date;
}
```

And here the code to take the info when user press a button.

```
$('.btn_graf').click(function() {
    if(id_btn == 'date_btn'){
        var from = datePickerRange();
        alert(from);           
    } 
});
```

Why returns `object object`? I think maybe I'm doing wrong the `return from;` because I have to add something more but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Can somebody help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: `datePickerRange()` returns a jQuery object. What are you expecting to see in the alert?

Answer (score 0):

`from` is the jQuery object representing the `#from` element, it's not useful to alert it. If you want to get the dates that the user has selected, use the [`getDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) method of the datepicker.

```
$('.btn_graf').click(function() {
    if(id_btn == 'date_btn'){
        var from = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");
        var to = $("#to").datepicker("getDate");
        alert(`From ${from} to ${to}`);           
    } 
});
```